# How to loop over 0 .. v.len() - 1 when v might be empty?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

What's the correct way to loop over `0 .. v.len() - 1` when the vector `v` might be empty?

Consider the following code, which prints all choices of 2 elements in a vector `[5, 6, 7]`:

```
fn main() {
  let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
  for i in 0 .. v.len() - 1 {
    for j in i + 1 .. v.len() {
      println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

It prints

```
5 6
5 7
6 7
```

as expected.

Now, if we instead have

```
let v: Vec<i32> = vec![];
```

then the program panics due to overflow, which is also expected.

**Q**: How to fix it without changing the structure and the logic of the program, and without involving signed integers?

The following are some examples of the workarounds that I don't want:

- Handling empty `v` separately (changes the logic). Overall, I don't want any checks that `v` is empty, e.g. by `if v.len() == 0 { 0 } else { v.len() - 1 }`
- Changing the order of loops (changes the logic and the output):

  ```
  for j in 0 .. v.len() {
      for i in 0 .. j {
  ```
- Shifting the indices (changes the logic):

  ```
  for i in 1 .. v.len() {
      for j in i .. v.len() {
          // Now i is shifted by 1
  ```
- Using i32 (casts):

  ```
  for i in 0 .. v.len() as i32 - 1 {
      for j in i + 1 .. v.len() as i32 {
          // cast i and j to usize
  ```

Overall, I hope that there is a clean way to handle `0 .. v.len() - 1` without any hacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that, if `i == v.len()-1`, nothing happens in the body of the outer loop, because `i+1..v.len()` is an empty iterator. Therefore, the simplest way to avoid integer underflows is simply to remove the `-1`:

```rust
fn main() {
  let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
  for i in 0 .. v.len() {
    for j in i + 1 .. v.len() {
      println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

produces

```
5 6
5 7
6 7
```

and if I replace `v` with `Vec::new()`, you get no output, as expected.

Comment: Ah, missed that, good one.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit more googling, I found [saturating_sub](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.saturating_sub) which "saturates at the numeric bounds instead of overflowing." So, `0usize.saturating_sub(1usize)` will be `0usize`, which results in range `0usize .. 0usize`, as desired.

```
fn main() {
  let v: Vec<i32> = vec![];
  for i in 0 .. v.len().saturating_sub(1) {
    for j in i + 1 .. v.len() {
      println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To address the issue of handling `0 .. v.len() - 1` when a vector `v` might be empty, we can use Rust's `checked_sub` method to safely subtract one from the length of the vector without risking an integer underflow. This method returns an `Option` that is `None` if the subtraction would result in an underflow, and `Some` with the result otherwise.

And here's how you can implement it in the code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
    if let Some(max_index) = v.len().checked_sub(1) {
        for i in 0..max_index {
            for j in i + 1..v.len() {
                println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    // If v is empty, the loop will not execute, avoiding the panic.
}
```

This code will work correctly even if the vector `v` is empty, as `checked_sub(1)` will return `None` and the loop will not execute. This solution does not change the structure or logic of the program, does not involve signed integers, and does not require handling the empty vector case separately.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with doing it properly and checking the vector-is-empty case explicitly?

```
let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
if !v.is_empty() {
    for i in 0..v.len() - 1 {
        for j in i + 1..v.len() {
            println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: It also makes no sense to run the code in a special case with a vector of length 1, so checking for `v.len() >= 2` would be even more correct.

Comment: Because I don't like handling something as a special case when it's not a special case (and it certainly wouldn't be if the integers were signed).

Comment: Lengths less than 2 are automatically special cases simply because line `println!("{} {}", v[i], v[j]);` requires a minimum vector length of 2, regardless of what type of data is stored in that vector.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators give us the tools we need here, no need to use indices.

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
    let mut v_iter = v.iter();
    while let Some(x) = v_iter.next() {
        for y in v_iter.as_slice() {
            println!("{x} {y}");
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: Just like in [jthulhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77710285/234590), this relies on the fact that the inner loop does nothing on the outer loop's last iteration.

[`std::slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), the iterator type for slices (as returned by `slice.iter()`), has a method named [`as_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#method.as_slice) that returns a slice of the remaining elements in the iterator. In order to be able to access this, we need to handle the iterator explicitly in the outer loop instead of having the `for` loop do this for us. This `while let Some(x) = v_iter.next()` pattern is basically what a `for` loop desugars to, with the major exception that the `while let` form doesn't consume the iterator, so we can use it within or even after the loop.

We can achieve the same result using `clone` instead of `as_slice` in this case, because we only use the result as an iterator. While `as_slice` is specific to the slice iterator (and perhaps a few others), `clone` is available on many more iterator types.

```
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![5, 6, 7];
    let mut v_iter = v.iter();
    while let Some(x) = v_iter.next() {
        for y in v_iter.clone() {
            println!("{x} {y}");
        }
    }
}
```